# Why can I run my testcafe test from the command line but not through a python subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, automated-tests, subprocess, testcafe

I am running some frontend tests on a project that I am working on using testcafe. The tests work great when I run them from the command line however when I put the same command into a python subprocess, the testcafe loading icon spins for about 2 minutes before giving me the error: "Cannot establish one or more browser conenctions". Is there something that the python subprocess is changing for testcafe to not run in a subprocess vs the command line?

The command I am trying to execute is "testcafe firefox tests/unit/customTest.js --testName EspEmpty --testNum 0".

**customTest.js:**

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const testName = argv.testName;
const testNum = argv.testNum;
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const dataSet = require('../../src/testData.json');

fixture("Custom Test").page('http://localhost:8080/Modules');

switch(testName) {
    case "EspEmpty":
        test('Esp Empty Unit Test', async t=> {
            ...
        });
    break;
}
```

**runTest.py**

```
cmd = subprocess.run(["testcafe", "firefox", "tests/unit/customTest.js", "--testName", f"{testName}", "--testNum", f"{testNum}"], text = True)
```

In the command line, I tried `testcafe firefox tests/unit/customTest.js --testName EspEmpty --testNum 0` and the test ran perfectly fine.

In the python file, I tried `subprocess.run(["testcafe", "firefox", "tests/unit/customTest.js", "--testName", f"{testName}", "--testNum", f"{testNum}"], text = True)` expecting the same result as the command line, but the testcafe loading icon spins for about 2 minutes before giving me the error:

```
ERROR Cannot establish one or more browser conenctions.
1 of 1 browser connections have not been established:
- firefox

Hints:
- Increase the value of the "browserInitTimeout" option if it is too low (currently: 2 minutes for local browsers and 6 minutes for remote browsers). This option determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.
- The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.
Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

I am running the python code as sudo too. Is this a problem with python subprocess or testcafe?

python version: 3.9.2
testcafe version: 1.18.6
nodeJS version: 12.12.0

Comment: Hi! I tried to reproduce this issue with the latest TestCafe version on both Windows and Ubuntu machines, but it is not reproducible on my side. Please try following these steps:

1. Update TestCafe to the latest version;
2. Kill all Firefox processes in your system;
3. Try running your code again.

If this doesn't help, please share a simple runnable project that illustrates the issue.

Comment: It turns out testcafe doesnt like when you run a python file as sudo. running the python file with just python3 works just fine...

Comment: Hello, this behavior looks strange. Most likely, it is not related to TestCafe. However, I still recommend that you update your NodeJS version as well as the TestCafe version. Also, you can try specifying the browser with an exact path instead of an alias: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402661/reference/testcafe-api/runner/browsers?search#specify-the-path-to-the-browser-executable  
For example, in my case: "path:/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin".

Comment: Alright thank you for the suggestions. I was running the python file as sudo python3 instead of just python3 and that seemed to be the issue. Running the file with just python3 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the python file as sudo python3 instead of just python3 and that seemed to be the issue. Running the file with just python3 fixes the issue